# Dynamic Number of fields to columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this database: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9c1f66/16

and I would like to produce an output like this for a certain DataEntry (in this case the one with id 1):

```
 RowId | field1       | field2       | field3       | field4
   1   | value_field1 | value_field2 | value_field3 | value_field4 |
```

I tried using pivot tables but I can't figure out how to do it properly.

Comment: You created a database in a database which is a notorious anti-pattern. I believe you are going to have a bad time.

Comment: Well from an application perspective I don't have any issues. The issue is that I have to provide an SQL for a third party software, first time I'm doing some kind of EAV models and as all the first times doing mistakes I normal, I guess.

Comment: I tried youf sqlfiddle and doesn't seem to work - no output shows. I can accomplish in Access. Unfortunately, MySQL does not have PIVOT syntax. Review https://codingsight.com/pivot-tables-in-mysql/#:~:text=Pivot%20Tables%20in%20MySQL%201%20Briefly%20about%20Pivot,4%20Automating%20data%20pivot%2C%20creating%20query%20dynamically.%20

Answer (score 0):

The SQL language has a very **strict and unbreakable rule** requiring you to know the number of columns returned by a query **before looking at any data in your tables**.

The only way around this is with dynamic SQL, where you complete the query over three steps:

1. Run a query to find out information about your target columns.
2. Use the information from the first step to build a complex new SQL statement on the fly, using a PIVOT, conditional aggregations, numerous JOINs to the same table, or some combination thereof.
3. Run the query from step 2.

The design you are pursuing will require you to jump through those hoops for pretty much every query you will want to run. This will make application maintenance and development much more complex, it will make executing the query itself slow, and possibly worst of all this will break your ability to effectively index your data.